# How to get submit button value in form builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, font-awesome

I'm creating a form using the `simple_form` gem on Rails 3.2.

The problem I'm having is that I wish to add a `font-awesome` icon to the `f.button :submit` line of my form. Since the output is of type `input` I can't embed the icon element inside of it.

I could simply hardcode a `submit` button into the form that contains the icon but I am not sure how to fetch the button value - `Create %model`/`Update %model`.

My code is posted below:

```
<div id="form">
  <%= simple_form_for @program, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :url %>
    <%= f.input :description, :input_html => { :class => "span5", :rows => 10 } %>

    *********************

    <%= f.button :submit do %>
      <i class="icon-save"></i> What Here??? <--- Doesn't work since output is type input
    <% end %>

    *********************

    <button class="btn">
      <i class="icon-save"></i> <%= f.button(:submit).label %> <--- Doesn't work, alternative?
    </button>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">
    <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Create *ModelName*        
</button>
```

Or Update *ModelName*, depending on controller action.

Comment: Can you show us how it's suppose to look like in html code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.button do %>
    <i class="icon-save"></i> <%= "#{f.object.new_record? ? 'Create' : 'Update'} #{f.object.class.model_name.human}" %>
<% end %>
```

It would be better to make some helper method for this. If you want to use I18n take a look at [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb) (`button` and `submit_default_value` methods, lines [1763](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1763) and [1776](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1776)). It's pretty clear.